# JavaScript issue: To create a table with data based on select list

Tags: javascript, html-table, drop-down-menu

I am new in Javascript and I have a list of env and I want to show the details in a table based on environment selected. However, I am able to show the environment selected but not the env details. Can someone help please?

this the code I am using:

```js
function func(x) {
  //alert(x.value);
  switch (x.value) {
    case "0":
      alert("Please select a option");
      break;
    case "ENV1":
      alert("selected ENV1");
      let mountains = [{
          name: "Linux Details",
          result: "env1@server"
        },
        {
          name: "Owner DB",
          result: "env1@db1"
        }
      ];
      break;
    case "ENV2":
      alert("ENV2");
      break;
    case "ENV3":
      alert("selected ENV3");
      break;
    case "ENV4":
      alert("selected ENV4");
      break;
    default: // called if the value is none of the above
      alert("Please select a option");
      break;
  }
}

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

function generateTable(table, data) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

let table = document.querySelector("table");
let data = Object.keys(mountains[0]);
generateTableHead(table, data);
generateTable(table, mountains);

function getOption() {
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
  output = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
  window.console.log("in here");
}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onChange="func(this)">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">--- Please select a env---</option>
  <option value="ENV1">ENV1</option>
  <option value="ENV2">ENV2</option>
  <option value="ENV3">ENV3</option>
  <option value="ENV4">ENV4</option>
  <option value="ENV5">ENV5</option>
  <option value="ENV6">ENV6</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getOption()">Check option</button>

<p> The environment selected is:
  <span class="output"></span>
</p>

<table>
  <!-- here goes our data! -->
</table>
```

The result is something like this:

Probably there I am missing something here.

Comment: Your code doesn't run because the `mountains` variable is missing.

Comment: You should be calling `generateTable(table, mountains)` from inside `func()`, since that's where you declare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ENV1

```html
<select id="select1" onChange = "func(this)" >
            <option selected="selected" value="0">--- Please select a env---</option>
            <option value="ENV1">ENV1</option>
            <option value="ENV2">ENV2</option>
            <option value="ENV3">ENV3</option>
            <option value="ENV4">ENV4</option>
            <option value="ENV5">ENV5</option>
            <option value="ENV6">ENV6</option>
</select>
    
<button onclick="getOption()">Check option</button>
    <p> The environment selected is: 
        <span class="output"></span> 
    </p>

<table>
<!-- here goes our data! -->
</table>

<script>                        
let mountains = [];            
function func(x) {
  switch(x.value) {
    case "0":
      alert("Please select a option");
      break;
    case "ENV1":
      alert("selected ENV1");
      mountains = [
        { name: "Linux Details", result: "env1@server" },
        { name: "Owner DB", result: "env1@db1" }
      ];            
      break;
    case "ENV2":
      alert("ENV2");
      break;
    case "ENV3":
      alert("selected ENV3");
      break;
    case "ENV4":
      alert("selected ENV4");
      break;
    default: // called if the value is none of the above
      alert("Please select a option");
      break;
  }
}
    
function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

function generateTable(table, data) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

function renderTable() {
  let table = document.querySelector("table");
  let data = Object.keys(mountains[0]);
  generateTableHead(table, data);
  generateTable(table, mountains);
}  
  
function getOption() {
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
  output = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
  window.console.log("in here");
  renderTable();
}   
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This made work!! I appreciate!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).